# Using Java threads to switch from concurrency to sequential access

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

I think I have a pretty simple problem, but I can't for the life of me figure it out (partly due to my inexperience with Java).

I am trying to read/write operations such that all read operations are concurrent (since the data is not modified), but write operations must be sequential.

Essentially, if I have an operations queue that looks like:

[R, R, R, W, R, R, W]

The first 3 reads will be handled concurrently,

but the first write operation will be blocked until the first 3 reads are done.

Once the first write is done, the next 2 reads are handled concurrently.

Likewise the second write operation is blocked until the 2 reads before are finished.

**My problem** :

I have a pool of threads that handle the Operations queue concurrently (using the take() method from LinkedBlockingQueue).

However, I don't know how to block the write operation--essentially how to wait for the threads doing read to finish.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `ReentrantReadWriteLock`: it provides exactly what you need. Some pseudocode:

```
private final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

private void read()
{
    lock.readLock().lock();
    try {
        ...
    } finally {
        lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
}

private void write()
{
    lock.writeLock().lock();
    try {
        ...
    } finally {
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good case for [Java's CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). It is specifically designed for blocking until multiple threads have completed their work.

You might use it with code like the following:

```
final CountDownLatch allWrittenSignal = new CountDownLatch(3);
List<Runnable> writeTasks = new ArrayList<>(3);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // do write work
      allWrittenSignal.countDown();
    }
  };
  writeTasks.add(task);
}

ExecutorService execSvc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
for (Runnable task : tasks) {
  execSvc.execute(task);
}
allWrittenSignal.await();
// now do read work
```

Comment: It really doesn't sound like a good case for `CountDownLatch`. It's a textbook example of ReadWriteLock.